# jquery passing control id into inner method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making ajax call(ASP.NET 3.5) from dropdown change handler and trying to pass dropdown id into ajax call:

```
$('select.facility').change(function()
{
      if ($(this).val() != 0)
      {
            var params = new Object();
            params.facilityId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $.toJSON(params),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "SomeURL.asmx/SomeMethod",
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        //this is where I need to get a hold of my dropdown,
                        // $(this) obviously doesn't work, using just to illustrate  
                        $(this).closest('table').next('table')
                        .find('input.address').val(response.d.Address);

                    }  

      }
});
```

Is there any elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this`, you just need to add the [`context` option of `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so `this` is useful:

```
$('select.facility').change(function() {   
   if ($(this).val() == 0) return;
   var params = { facilityId = $(this).val() };
   $.ajax({
      context: this,                           //add this!
      type: "POST",
      data: $.toJSON(params),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "SomeURL.asmx/SomeMethod",
      success: function(response) {
        $(this).closest('table').next('table')
               .find('input.address').val(response.d.Address);
      }  
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks, this is most elegant way of doing it
Btw looks like you wouldn't be able to use this `params` syntax if you had multiple parameters to pass

Comment: @Victor - You can, it would look like this:  `var params = { name1: 'value1', name2: 'value2' }`, just use a comma between pairs :)

Answer (score 1):

```
...
var parentContext = $(this);
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    data: $.toJSON(params),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "SomeURL.asmx/SomeMethod",
    success: function(response)
    {
        //this is where I need to get a hold of my dropdown,
        // $(this) obviously doesn't work, using just to illustrate  
        parentContext.closest('table').next('table')
        .find('input.address').val(response.d.Address);

    }  
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on using AJAX you could simply set the [`AutoPostback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) property of your dropdown to true and handle the changed event in the code behind.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I do insist on AJAX for multiple reasons.